# What is this.emoji in this example?

Tags: angular, emoji

I am trying this library called  [ngx-emoji-mart](https://github.com/TypeCtrl/ngx-emoji-mart), i want to show the selected emoji in my input field. I was reading the document and found this. But I am not able to find what they mean by "this.emoji". so I have few questions:

1. What is "this.emoji" in below code and how to initialze it??
2. I think this the solution to show selected emoji inside a div, but how can I show the emoji **with skin color** inside my input field?
3. How do I save my chat with emoji?

Lets say user is typing in a input field "Hi John !! , how are you?" then what should be my final text to save in DB? How will I render it correctly when user want to see his chat history ?? 
If i store my text like this:

> Hi John !! :slightly_smiling_face:, how are you?

Than how will I display it in div with respective emoji? Do I need to write any directive which will search text like ":emoji id:" and replace it with

```
<ngx-emoji emoji=':santa::skin-tone-3:' size="16"></ngx-emoji>
```

Thanks.

```
Display emoji as custom element
// $event is from (emojiClick)
const styles = this.emoji.emojiSpriteStyles($event.emoji.sheet, 'twitter'); // pass emoji sheet
const el = document.createElement('div');
Object.assign(el.style, styles); // apply styles to new element
document.body.appendChild(el);
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` is the current context. Respectively it is the object on which the method, whose code you have partially quoted above - was called. And `emoji` is a property or attribute of `this` respectively of the mentioned object.

Explanation by example:

```
o = { emoji: '',
      print: function() {  console.log(this.emoji); };

o.print();
```

Comment: Thanks Tomás, but my question is that it is not clear in the document ho to initialize this.emoji, is it a service i need to inject in constructor .. or it is just variable in component which I have initialized?? Any idea???

Comment: @Susan Most of the time in Angular, the `this` context will refer to the component class. I found the example you gave, and yeah--there's no context for what `emoji` is defined as. Searching the repo for the method name being called on it, it looks like it's a property of an `EmojiService`: https://github.com/TypeCtrl/ngx-emoji-mart/search?q=emojiSpriteStyles&unscoped_q=emojiSpriteStyles.  So yes, looks like `this.emoji` would be referring to an injected service.

Comment: you are very kind, but re-reading your question, I didn't really contribute anything. Not being an angular head myself, I can only guess: based on @joh04667 (who's much more on point) you need to create an EmojiService object and assign it to this.emoji.

Answer (score 1):

as @Tomáš Pospíšek stated, `this` is contextually referring to the 'current' object.

In Angular, `this` almost always refers to the component class you're defining.

It's common for third-party bundles like this to offer functionality in component code by providing a service.

I checked that repo, and yeah, it looks like that code sample is just there without great documentation or mention of an injectable service.

I searched the repo for the method being called off `emoji`, [emojiSpriteStyles](https://github.com/TypeCtrl/ngx-emoji-mart/search?q=emojiSpriteStyles&unscoped_q=emojiSpriteStyles).

Looks like it's in an `EmojiService`. Just inject that service.

Comment: worked .. so one first problem is solved :) Thanks @joh04667. Just in case you have any suggestion for 2 and 3 ? I can not upvote though :(

Comment: 2. -> I pretty sure emojis with different skin color are different emojis. You'll need to explore the existing emojis.

Comment: Those solutions require more familiarity with that library -- StackOverflow's goal is to be a repository of focused, widely applicable knowledge. General questions like those aren't really the point of the forum, and may get taken down. Might I suggest you try and work on those things until you have a more specific question preventing you from reaching your goal? i.e. your third question might boil down to "How do I convert a Unicode character to a varchar and store it in SSMS?" Those questions follow the guidelines and get far more attention.

Answer (score 0):

Sample snippet in reference to joh04667's answer:

First import the EmojiService

```
import { EmojiService } from '@ctrl/ngx-emoji-mart/ngx-emoji';
```

then inject the service in the constructor

```
constructor( private emoji: EmojiService) { }
```

then you could access the emojiSpriteStyles method and other properties of the emoji object.